# angular directive scope before return

Tags: angularjs

I need to access a scope variable before entering the return of a directive.

I have a directive which returns a select element with options for each of the trucks.

```
<tc-vehicle-select label="Truck" selected="activeDailyLog.truck"></tc-vehicle-select>
```

I need to use the selected value in the directive to put a `selected` tag on the appropriate option element.

```
.directive('tcVehicleSelect', function(localStorageService) {
  /* Get a list of trucks for the organization and populate a select element for
     the user to choose the appropriate truck.
  */

  var trucks = localStorageService.get('trucks');
  var truckHtml;

  for (var i = 0; i < trucks.length; i++) {
    var truck = trucks[i];
    var injectText;

    if(truck.description){
      injectText = truck.description
    }else{
      injectText = 'truck ' + truck.id
    }

    truckHtml += '<option value="' + truck.id + '">' + injectText + '</option>'
  }

  return {
      scope: {
        label: '@',
        active: '@'
      },
      replace: true,
      template: '<label class="item item-input item-select">' +
                '<div class="input-label">{{label}}</div>' +
                '<select ng-model="timeLog.truck"><option value="">None</option>' + truckHtml +
                '</select></label>'
  };
});
```

I have everything working in this directive except I'm stuck on setting the `selected` attribute on the correct element. If I could access the `selected` variable passed in I would be able to do it by inserting into the truckHtml, but I haven't found examples using that - only using the variables below in the retrun block.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: Also wanted to clarify that the `activeDailyLog.truck` in the HTML has the correct value I'm looking for.

Comment: The code you put in the factory function above the return will only get called once, even if you have five instances of the directive. Just a friendly note :)

Comment: One point, i am not sure if your ng-model will work in the isolated scope.

Comment: @BroiSatse I am now seeing that, it fooled me before and I thought it was working, but it actually wasn't. So now there are 2 things wrong with this, but I'll work that issue out separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It makes sense to place your directive's code inside the `link` function.
2. To retrieve the passed scope variable inside the directive, use `=` for two-way binding to the same object.

Code:

```
.directive('tcVehicleSelect', function(localStorageService) {
  /* Get a list of trucks for the organization and populate a select element for
     the user to choose the appropriate truck.
  */
  return {
      scope: {
        selected: '='
      },
      replace: true,
      template: '<label class="item item-input item-select">' +
                '<div class="input-label">{{label}}</div>' +
                '<select ng-model="timeLog.truck"><option value="">None</option>' + truckHtml +
                '</select></label>',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        var trucks = localStorageService.get('trucks');
        trucks.forEach(function(truck) {
          var injectText;
          if(truck.description){
            injectText = truck.description
          } else {
            injectText = 'truck ' + truck.id
          }

          truckHtml += '<option value="' + truck.id + '">' + injectText + '</option>'
        }

        // Access scope.selected here //
        console.log(scope.selected);  
      }
  };
});
```

3. Also replaced with `Array.forEach()` method, as it seemed more relevant in this context!

Answer (score 0):

Internally there are very few differences between directive and a factory. The most important thing here is that directives are cached - your code is only run once and angular will keep reusing its return value every time it needs to use that directive.

That being said, you cannot access scope within directive declaration body - if you could it would be a scope of the first directive and its result would be cached and used for all other places you would use same directive.

I do like the idea of building the options before the return though, assuming you are sure it will not change during the application life (as it will save you from some unnecessary bindings). However, it is usually not true, so I would rather move the whole logic into a compile or even link function:

```
.directive('tcVehicleSelect', function(localStorageService) {

  return {
      scope: {
        label: '@',
        active: '@'
      },
      replace: true,
      template: '<label class="item item-input item-select">' +
                '<div class="input-label">{{label}}</div>' +
                '<select ng-model="timeLog.truck"><option value="">None</option>'
                '</select></label>',
      link: function(scope, element) {
              var trucks = localStorageService.get('trucks'),
                  select = element.find('select');
                  option;
              trucks.forEach(function(truck) {
                option = angular.element('<option></option>');
                option.attr('value', truck.id);
                option.html(truck.description || "truck" + truck.id);
                if (truck.id === scope.selected.id) {                  
                  option.attribute('selected', 'selected');
                }
                select.append(option);
             });
     }
  };
});
```